# Telerik RadEditor dialogs rendering in random element

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, radeditor

Please see this screenshot:

http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/3349/radeditorweirdness.jpg

The radEditor dialogs are rendering within a form on my master page.. and I can't for the life of me figure out why..

Wouldn't it try and render somewhere up the DOM that was more "local" to it than in my master page?

It should be noted that this only just started happening.. I've changed some styles that are loaded throughout my site... but nothing that would affect the radEditor. I've also double checked that all of my styles are correct and not broken.. I can't think of anything else? Firebug doesn't report any issues at all.

I should also probably mention that there are 3 forms on this particular page. 1 in the master page (where it is being rendered), and 2 in the content page (the RadEditor is contained in only one of them).

Any help would be appreciated.

Server side is ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor)

Regards,

chem

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design - the editor dialogs and the modal overlay will be rendered as the last elements on the ASP.NET form tag. This is done to prevent any interference with CSS styles you might have in the inner parts of the page where the actual RadEditor control is rendered - it is assumed that the form tag is the outer-most tag with runat="server" you have in the body of the page. Since these are absolutely positioned elements, their place in the DOM tree is not important for their actual position. Furthermore, the elements should be disposed correctly with the editor, so they will not be left over after the page is unloaded.

Comment: But this is ASP.NET MVC, so I don't have a runat attribute. This only JUST started happening randomly.. this particular page has always had a vanilla HTML form (without runat attribute) on it in the masterpage. Looking in firebug, they are fixed at 0, 0 - and they still appear as in the above screenshot. I have since removed the first form and it all renders correctly. Is there a known way to make it "skip" the first form?

Comment: I have updated my question to show that there are 3 vanilla HTML forms on the page, 1 in the masterpage, 2 in the View (content page)

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a bug report to Telerik, who have confirmed this is the reason for RestrictedZone's when dealing with their controls. You can define a "restricted zone", and the RadWindow's won't render within that area.

I could not find that online anywhere.. so if anyone else gets this problem.. thats the answer!

chem